# Serilog multiple files appsettings.json

Tags: c#, serilog

Im trying to configure serilog to write to multiple files, with no luck whatsoever.
With this configuration it just writes to the second file?

```json
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "c:\\temp\\audit-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "c:\\temp\\error-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or is there any way to load many loggers to the software with different configurations from appsettings.json. Something like this?

```cs
var errorLogConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

_log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom
    .Configuration(errorLogConfiguration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution. Created separate sections to appsettings.json, ErrorLog and AuditLog.

```
  "ErrorLog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "c:\\temp\\error-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "AuditLog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "c:\\temp\\audit-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now I can create 2 separate loggers:

```cs
            var errorLogConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var errorSection = errorLogConfiguration.GetSection("ErrorLog");
            var auditSection = errorLogConfiguration.GetSection("AuditLog");

            _log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom
                .ConfigurationSection(errorSection)
                .CreateLogger();

            _auditLog = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom
                .ConfigurationSection(auditSection)
                .CreateLogger();
```

Which suits my need better.

Answer (score 7):

After struggling for days due to the simple documentation for Serilog and any of the sinks, this is what finally worked for me without creating any separate logger:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Async" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithDemystifiedStackTraces" ],
    "WriteTo:Information": {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
            "Configure": [
                {
                    "Name": "RollingFile",
                    "Args": {
                        "RestrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
                        "Formatter": "FOOINC.API.Configuration.Logging.CustomRenderedCompactJsonFormatter, FOOINC.API.Configuration",
                        "PathFormat": "_logs\\info\\info-log.json"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "WriteTo:Error": {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
            "Configure": [
                {
                    "Name": "RollingFile",
                    "Args": {
                        "RestrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
                        "Formatter": "FOOINC.API.Configuration.Logging.CustomRenderedCompactJsonFormatter, FOOINC.API.Configuration",
                        "PathFormat": "_logs\\errors\\error-log.json"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone out there!!

Comment: Please explain the idea of the solution. I would had upvoted it if you had.

Comment: The idea is simple, we required two types of loggers, one with no filters and one exclusively with the errors (for different purposes) and we didn't want different Serilog instances.

In addition to that by having this setup, we can output logs (filtered or not) to other types of sinks like debug, seq, etc.

Answer (score 5):

My findings after a while of errors, retry and nearly giving up based on lack of documentation about Serilog. They have a tread on GitHub: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-filters-expressions/issues/27. Nearly every thread goes to the same conclusion that you have to create a SUBLOGGER. This is my implementation. For this implementation you need the following plugins:

- Serilog Filter
- Serilog Sink
- Serilog Async

  ```
  "Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo:Information": { //this name here can be changed
    "Name": "Logger", //this name here is essential
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "@Level = 'Information'"
            }
          }
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "Async", //i use async plugin from serilog
            "Args": {
              "configure": [
                {
                  "Name": "File",
                  "Args": {
                    "path": "Logs/Log_.txt",
                    "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
                    "rollingInterval": "Day",
                    "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  ```

Answer (score 3):

There is little documentation on logger settings through the configuration file. Can anyone help - just an example of using the settings of the logger. In the example - all logs are written in one sample.txt. Logs on a call of a certain API / api/health - in a separate file and are not included in sample.txt. And an example ad - IMyLogger-writes to a separate SampleMy.txt. You can add many sections, and divide the logs by different criteria. It is better to set local logging levels as minimal, they will be overwritten by the global level. The global filter will exclude logs from all sub-loggers (I don't use it). PS sorry for the bad English)

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information", //<- global error level. Ovveride all local error level
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "MinimumLevel": "Debug", // <- local error level. 
            //Only records with Information logging level will be written to the log file
           //but if ovveride global level to Debug, and dont override local error level -> it will still be global
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "log\\SampleHealthCheck-.txt", //write health-check log in different file
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] [CorrId:{CorrelationId}] [Op:{OperationId}] [U:{UserName}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "RequestPath like '%/api/health'"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "log\\SampleMy-.txt", //Write some log in different file. Control through code 
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] [CorrId:{CorrelationId}] [Op:{OperationId}] [U:{UserName}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "SourceContext = 'MyProject.IMyLogger'"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "MinimumLevel": "Information",
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "log\\Sample-.txt", //all logs, without health-check
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] [CorrId:{CorrelationId}] [Op:{OperationId}] [U:{UserName}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "RequestPath like '%/api/health'"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "WithProcessName"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Sample",
      "Environment": "Test"
    }
  }

public class MyCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<MyCommand, Unit>
{
    private readonly ILogger _myLogger;
    private static int _count;

    public MyCommandHandler()
    {
        _myLogger = Log.ForContext<IMyLogger>();
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(MyCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _count++;

        Log.Debug("MyCommandHandler Count call = {count}",_count ); //write sample.txt
        Log.Information("MyCommandHandler Count call = {count}",_count ); //write in sample.txt
        Log.Error("MyCommandHandler Count call = {count}",_count); //write in sample.txt

        _myLogger.Information("Log from IMyLogger", _count); //write in sample.txt and in sampleMy.txt

        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have got a cool solution from a blog i have found. It surely did perform like a charm. if any problem occurs pls let me know. I am also sharing the blog with you guys  https://www.techrepository.in/blog/posts/writing-logs-to-different-files-serilog-asp-net-core. Also for filtering the logs you need to use **Serilog.Eexpressions** nuget package.
Hope you get what you are looking for from here

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Expressions"  ],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug"
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "@l = 'Error' or @l = 'Fatal' or @l = 'Warning'"
            }
          }
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
              "path": "../logs/error_.log",
              "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
              "rollingInterval": "Day"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "@l = 'Information' or @l = 'Debug'"
            }
          }
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
              "path": "../logs/debug_.log",
              "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
              "rollingInterval": "Day"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]},
```

Works 100%. try it out!!

Answer (score -1):

I made some tests on this issue. The good news is your configuration works. Your error files probably isn't created, because no error is logged.

Serilog will create the log file, when the first message is logged into that file. You can confirm this if you run this simple program and (un)comment the logging of an error.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var errorLogConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom
            .Configuration(errorLogConfiguration)
            .CreateLogger();
        log.Warning("Warning");
        log.Error("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: That configuration doesn't actually work, and yes I did log errors.

Comment: Can you tell me the versions of the nuget packages you are using? I hate this sentence, but it works on _my_ machine,

Comment: No worries.     <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.0.0" />

Comment: Ok, Then the issue is probably asp.net-core related. I was using a simple console applications. But since you've found an other solution i won't investigate this further.